# Getting DOM elements by classname

Tags: php, css, dom

I'm using [PHP DOM](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) and I'm trying to get an element within a DOM node that have a given class name.  What's the best way to get that sub-element?

**Update:** I ended up using `Mechanize` for PHP which was much easier to work with.

Comment: Reletated: [PHP dom to get tag class with multiple css class name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4835300/php-dom-to-get-tag-class-with-multiple-css-class-name)

Answer (score 181, accepted):

**Update: Xpath version of `*[@class~='my-class']` css selector**

So after my comment below in response to hakre's comment, I got curious and looked into the code behind `Zend_Dom_Query`. It looks like the above selector is compiled to the following xpath (untested):

`[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' my-class ')]`

So the PHP would be:

```
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->load($filePath);
$finder = new DomXPath($dom);
$classname="my-class";
$nodes = $finder->query("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' $classname ')]");
```

Basically, all we do here is normalize the `class` attribute so that even a single class is bounded by spaces, and the complete class list is bounded in spaces. Then append the class we are searching for with a space. This way we are effectively looking for and find only instances of `my-class` .

---

Use an xpath selector?

```
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->load($filePath);
$finder = new DomXPath($dom);
$classname="my-class";
$nodes = $finder->query("//*[contains(@class, '$classname')]");
```

If it is only ever one type of element you can replace the `*` with the particular tagname.

If you need to do a lot of this with very complex selector I would recommend [`Zend_Dom_Query`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.dom.query.html) which supports CSS selector syntax (a la jQuery):

```
$finder = new Zend_Dom_Query($html);
$classname = 'my-class';
$nodes = $finder->query("*[class~=\"$classname\"]");
```

Comment: finds the class `my-class2` as well, but pretty sweet. Any way to only pick the first of all elements?

Comment: I dont think you can without xpath2... However the example for Zend_Dom_Query does exactly that. IF you dont want to use that compkenet in your project then you might want to see how they are translating that css selector to xpath. Maybe DomXPath supports xpath 2.0 - im not sure about that.

Comment: @prodigitalson: Thanks much for your answer.  I went and taught myself XPath and had a question.. Why do you use use contains, rather than simply doing [@class="$classname"]?

Comment: because `class` can have more than one class for example: `<a class="my-link link-button nav-item">`.

Comment: @prodigitalson: This is incorrect as it does not reflect the spaces, try `//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' classname ')]` (Very informative: [CSS Selectors And XPath Expressions](http://www.a-basketful-of-papayas.net/2010/04/css-selectors-and-xpath-expressions.html)).

Comment: @hakare: am i mistaken or is the only differene the leading space? because technically that wouldnt matter anything ` classname ` matches will alos be matched by `classname `. GOOD LINK. Whis i had found that instead o reading the code in `Zend_Dom_Query`... would have been faster, haha.

Comment: so..contains would still be the way to go?

Comment: @babonk: yes, you need to use `contains` in combination with `concat`... we are jsut discussing the particulars of padding the spaces on both sides of the class youre searching for or only padding one side. Either should work though.

Comment: @babonk: also make sure you take a look at the [link hakre posted in his comment to my answer](http://www.a-basketful-of-papayas.net/2010/04/css-selectors-and-xpath-expressions.html). There is a wealth of good info there dealing with xpath in comparison to css selectors.

Answer (score 27):

If you wish to get the innerhtml of the class without the zend you could use this:

```
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->load($filePath);
$classname = 'main-article';
$finder = new DomXPath($dom);
$nodes = $finder->query("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' $classname ')]");
$tmp_dom = new DOMDocument(); 
foreach ($nodes as $node) 
    {
    $tmp_dom->appendChild($tmp_dom->importNode($node,true));
    }
$innerHTML.=trim($tmp_dom->saveHTML()); 
echo $innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 19):

I think the accepted way is better, but I guess this might work as well

```
function getElementByClass(&$parentNode, $tagName, $className, $offset = 0) {
    $response = false;

    $childNodeList = $parentNode->getElementsByTagName($tagName);
    $tagCount = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $childNodeList->length; $i++) {
        $temp = $childNodeList->item($i);
        if (stripos($temp->getAttribute('class'), $className) !== false) {
            if ($tagCount == $offset) {
                $response = $temp;
                break;
            }

            $tagCount++;
        }

    }

    return $response;
}
```

Comment: Where is the example for this? It would've been nice.

Comment: That's great. I got the element with the class. Now I want to edit content of the element, like append child to the element containing the class. How to append the child and recreate whole HTML? Please help. This is what I have done. `$classResult = getElementByClass($dom, 'div', 'm-signature-pad');
                        $classResult->nodeValue = '';
                        $enode = $dom->createElement('img');
                        $enode->setAttribute('src', $signatureImage);
                        $classResult->appendChild($enode);`

Comment: for dom modification by php I think its better to use phpquery https://github.com/punkave/phpQuery

Answer (score 14):

There is also another approach without the use of `DomXPath` or `Zend_Dom_Query`.

Based on dav's original function, I wrote the following function that returns all the children of the parent node whose tag and class match the parameters.

```
function getElementsByClass(&$parentNode, $tagName, $className) {
    $nodes=array();

    $childNodeList = $parentNode->getElementsByTagName($tagName);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $childNodeList->length; $i++) {
        $temp = $childNodeList->item($i);
        if (stripos($temp->getAttribute('class'), $className) !== false) {
            $nodes[]=$temp;
        }
    }

    return $nodes;
}
```

suppose you have a variable `$html` the following HTML:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <div id="content_node">
    <p class="a">I am in the content node.</p>
    <p class="a">I am in the content node.</p>
    <p class="a">I am in the content node.</p>    
  </div>
  <div id="footer_node">
    <p class="a">I am in the footer node.</p>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

use of `getElementsByClass` is as simple as:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$content_node=$dom->getElementById("content_node");

$div_a_class_nodes=getElementsByClass($content_node, 'div', 'a');//will contain the three nodes under "content_node".
```

Answer (score 13):

**DOMDocument** is slow to type and **phpQuery** has bad memory leak issues. I ended up using:

https://github.com/wasinger/htmlpagedom

To select a class:

```
include 'includes/simple_html_dom.php';

$doc = str_get_html($html);
$href = $doc->find('.lastPage')[0]->href;
```

I hope this helps someone else as well

Comment: So simple, so beautiful! Usability at it's very finest, compared to PHP's native DOM handling! Please upvote, this is the most useful answer.

Answer (score 5):

PHP's native DOM handling is so absurdly bad, do yourself a favour and use this or any other modern HTML parsing package which can handle this within in few lines:

Install [paquettg/php-html-parser](https://github.com/paquettg/php-html-parser) with

```sh
composer require paquettg/php-html-parser
```

Then create a .php file in the same folder with this content

```php
<?php

// load dependencies via Composer
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use PHPHtmlParser\Dom;

$dom = new Dom;
$dom->loadFromUrl("https://example.com");
$links = $dom->find('.classname a');

foreach ($links as $link) {
    echo $link->getAttribute('href');
}
```

P.S. You'll find information on how to install Composer on [Composer's homepage](https://getcomposer.org/).

Answer (score 4):

I prefer using Symfony for this. Their libraries are pretty nice.

Use the [The DomCrawler Component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html#resolving-a-uri)

**Example:**

```
$browser = new HttpBrowser(HttpClient::create());
$crawler = $browser->request('GET', 'example.com');
$class = $crawler->filter('.class')->first();
```

Comment: Quite a lot of power between those BrowserKit and DomCrawler components!