# How to get html code of DOMElement node?

Tags: php, dom, domdocument, dom-node

I have this html code:

```
<html>
    <head>
    ...
    </head>
<body>
    <div>
    <div class="foo" data-type="bar">
        SOMECONTENTWITHMORETAGS
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I already can get the "foo" element (but only its content) with this function:

```
private function get_html_from_node($node){
  $html = '';
  $children = $node->childNodes;

  foreach ($children as $child) {
    $tmp_doc = new DOMDocument();
    $tmp_doc->appendChild($tmp_doc->importNode($child,true));
    $html .= $tmp_doc->saveHTML();
  } 
  return $html;
}
```

But I'd like to return all html tags (including its attributes) of DOMElement. How I can do that?

Comment: If you are trying to get `html_from_node` `class="foo"` you are doing it not correct. There is much easy and short way of doing this.

Comment: Is this helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6366351/getting-dom-elements-by-class-name

Comment: @webbandit I know there is a better way. Please show me!

Comment: Note: This is not duplicate, as it's asking to return html of DOMElement, not DOMDocument as in other question, and these questions have already different answers.

Comment: @kenorb hey, it's SO. every question is a duplicate now by definition 

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Use the optional argument to [`DOMDocument::saveHTML`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtml.php): this says "output this element only".

```
return $node->ownerDocument->saveHTML($node);
```

Note that the argument is only available from PHP 5.3.6. Before that, you need to use [`DOMDocument::saveXML`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savexml.php) instead. The results may be slightly different. Also, if you already have a reference to the document, you can just do this:

```
$doc->saveHTML($node);
```

Comment: This is actually what I need but it's for an WordPress plugin which should work with version 3.4 and this versions requires php 5.2.4.

Comment: @revaxarts Then use `saveXML`. The output will be little different...

Comment: u point me to a full example? I don't have a reference of the document in the function only the node and `DOMDocument::saveXML($node)` is not working same as `$node->saveXML($node)`

Comment: @revaxarts The code you'll need is `$node->ownerDocument->saveXML($node)`.

Comment: ok, great thanks! Is there a documentation what is different to `saveHTML` and which php version is required?

Comment: @revaxarts See the two PHP manual pages linked in my answer.

Comment: I can't post full code as an answer, but this answer is incorrect. Here's the working code: https://gist.github.com/komlenic/1374083

Comment: This answer is incorrect @c00000fd You are a life saver ...  your link saved my life.

Comment: That code surely does something entirely different, @ClainDsilva.

Answer (score -11):

[PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) should do the job!

Comment: At least provide a snippet or use case example next time