# Get DOM element string using PHP

Tags: php, html, preg-match, domdocument

I have a set of html strings that can look like this:

```
<div id="myelementID" class="hello" data-foo="bar"> ... </div>
```

or

```
<div id="myelementID" class="world" data-this="that"> ... </div>
```

etc etc, you get the idea. Except for `id="myelementID"`, every other attribute else is not fixed.

What I need is to extract the exact string of the the `<div>`, eg. `<div id="myelementID" class="hello" data-foo="bar">` if an element with the ID "myelementID" exists.

As of now, I'm able to use DomDocument to check if the element exists:

```
        $dom = new DomDocument;
        $dom->validateOnParse = true;
        $internalErrors = libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
        $dom->loadHTML($html_string);
        libxml_use_internal_errors($internalErrors);
        $el = $dom->getElementById("myelementID");
```

From here, how can I get the element's HTML string? I'm open to using preg_match as well, which may be an even better solution.

**edit** 
Just to be clearer, I'm not looking for the content of the element. I'm looking for the string `<div id="myelementID" etc="etc" this="that">`. Because it's not certain what attributes the element has apart from the fact that it's ID is "myelementID", that's why I'm having the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get html code of DOMElement node?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12909787/how-to-get-html-code-of-domelement-node)

Comment: I've read that thread already. It's not a duplicate, it's about a different issue, and there's no valid answer.

Comment: I think you can use regexp in that case yes. Something like `if(preg_match("#<div id="myelementID"[^>]*>(.*)<\/div>"#,$el,$match) > 0)` would be sufficient, with $match[1] having your content

Comment: Don't... regex... html...

Comment: Your regex throws an error.

Comment: So why it's about different issue? Have you tried that `saveHTML`? What it outputs and what you need?

Comment: Not sure if it's because the question wasn't clear, but I'm not looking for the content of the element, but the string `<div id="myelementID" something="something" etc etc>` itself.

Comment: @MikeFeng Check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `DOMNode::C14N` method to canonicalize nodes to a string, `substr` and `strpos` functions to get the needed fragment :

```
...
$el = $dom->getElementById("myelementID");
$elString = $el->C14N();

var_dump(substr($elString, 0, strpos($elString, '>') + 1));
```

The output (for your example):

```
string(51) "<div class="hello" data-foo="bar" id="myelementID">"
```

http://php.net/manual/ru/domnode.c14n.php

Comment: No no, you're reading the question wrong. I don't want the content of the element. I just want `<div class="hello" data-foo="bar" id="myelementID">`

Answer (score 1):

A very simple Regex which works ([tested on RegExr](http://regexr.com/3dlb3)). The only downside to this is that any attributes of the `<div>` which contain a `>` would cause a premature end of the `<div>`.

```
<[^>]*\sid="myelementID"[^>]*>
```

A breakdown of the RegEx:

- `<` the opening tag of `<div`
- `[^>]*` match any number of characters that are not `>`
- `\s` matches a whitespace character (i.e. a space)
- `id="myelementID"` matches the id of your target element
- `[^>]*` match any number of characters that are not `>`
- `>` the end of the `<div>` tag

Comment: Looks like @RomanPerekhrest got there first, but I'd already started so thought I might as well finish!

Answer (score 0):

You can use bottom code if you want to use `DomDocument`. In bottom code, i used `foreach()` to iterate element attributes then store attribute name and attribute value in `$elemString` variable.

```
$html_string = '<div id="myelem4entID" class="hello" data-foo="bar">...</div>';

$dom = new DomDocument;
$dom -> loadHTML($html_string);
$el = $dom -> getElementById("myelementID");

if (!empty($el))
{
    $elemString = "<div";
    foreach ($el -> attributes as $attr) 
    {
        $name = $attr -> nodeName;
        $value = $attr -> nodeValue;    
        $elemString .= " {$name}=\"{$value}\"";
    }
    $elemString .= ">";
}
```

Test it in **[demo](https://ideone.com/McR9zy)**