# php DOMDocument find class extract id value

Tags: php, class, element, extract, domdocument

i have this html  from stagram :

```
<div id="photo351321902758808423_176859145" class="photoeach">
    <div class="photoeachinner">
        <div class="left">
            <div class="photowrapper">
                <div class="infomation_box clearfix">
                    <div class="profimage_small">

<div id="photo351295515670923844_176859145" class="photoeach">
    <div class="photoeachinner">
        <div class="left">
            <div class="photowrapper">
                <div class="infomation_box clearfix">
```

i need find class photoeach and extract id  352034826703915686_176859145

i did with regex but no luck , so im trying do it with domdocument

i followed step from 
[Getting DOM elements by classname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6366351/getting-dom-elements-by-class-name)

```
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->load($filePath);
$finder = new DomXPath($dom);
$classname="photoeach";
$nodes = $finder->query("//*[contains(@class, '$classname')]");
```

but i cant firgure it out how i can extract ID

Comment: So you want to extract an `id` that isn't present in the document?

Comment: "so im trying do it with domdocument" So... what have you tried?

Comment: i tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6366351/getting-dom-elements-by-class-name  there is no refrence for getting id

Comment: You just need to iterate over `$nodes` (which you can do with `foreach`) and `getAttribute('id')` - you are 99% of the way there!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Dave already mentioned you are not really that far off:

```
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->load($filePath);
$finder = new DomXPath($dom);
$classname="photoeach";
$nodes = $finder->query("//*[@class = '$classname']");

foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    echo 'Id: ' , substr($node->getAttribute('id'), 5) , '<br>';
}
```

Demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/xEdYLr

*Note that I have changed the `contains` selector of the class to only match exact matches, otherwise the `photoeachinner` would also be matched. If this is not what you want you can easily revert that change.*