# How to get the value using Regex?

Tags: php, regex

Hello I have a problem with my Regex code I use to get a value out of a HTML-tag using PHP. I have the following strings possible:

```
<span class="down last_position">xyz</span>
<span class="up last_position">xyz</span>
<span class="last_position new">xyz</span>
```

And I have the following preg_match command:

```
preg_match('#<span class="last_position.*?">(.+)</span>#', $string, $matches);
```

Which pretty much just covers case #3. So I was wondering what I would need to add in front of last_position to get all cases possible..?

Thanks a lot..

Edit: For all who are wondering what value is to be matched: "xyz"

Comment: Don't use regex to parse HTML. While there are cases where regex can be used, the task that you are doing is best done with a HTML parser.

Comment: Yes I know, I am using DomDocument for the whole parsing.. I was just wondering if somebody would know...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6366351/getting-dom-elements-by-class-name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following (and yes you can use regex to match data from HTML):

```
$string = '<span class="down last_position">xyz</span>
<span class="up last_position">xyz</span>
<span class="last_position new">xyz</span>';

preg_match_all('#<span\s.*?class=".*?last_position.*?".*?>(.+?)</span>#i', $string, $m);
print_r($m);
```

[Online demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/zE6iuk).

Comment: I accepted this answer as the answer, due to my question was not how to do it with DomDocument but with Regex. And it was very detailed, thank you :)

Comment: please explain the pattern. Why does this work?

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV: `almost all situations` How do you quantify "almost all"? http://regex101.com/r/tZ3pA2 I can't do anything about my votes, since it is locked, but I don't think this answer deserve an upvote.

Comment: @nhahtdh Ok you got me there, I'm not gonna argue since you're against  the idea of using regex for HTML in the first place.

Answer (score 5):

Avoid using regex to parse HTML as it can be error prone. Your specific UseCase is better solved with a DOM parser:

```
$html = <<< EOF
<span class="down last_position">xyz</span>
<span class="up last_position">xyz</span>
<span class="last_position new">xyz</span>
EOF;
$doc = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTML($html); // loads your html
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$nodeList = $xpath->query("//span[contains(@class, 'last_position')]/text()");
for($i=0; $i < $nodeList->length; $i++) {
    $node = $nodeList->item($i);
    var_dump($node->nodeValue);
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
string(3) "xyz"
string(3) "xyz"
string(3) "xyz"
```

Comment: And about performance what is the best to use Dom or preg_match_all ?

Comment: @ElSinus: People complain about regex performances as well. So i'm note sure which one will be faster.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this

```
preg_match('#<span class="?(.*)last_position.*?">(.+)</span>#', $string, $matches);
```

Comment: Note that if a bunch of span tags are on the same line, this is not going to work.

Comment: @nhahtdh it's not mentioned in the question.

Comment: It depends on how much assumption you want to make. Currently, it is going to break very easily over a change in new line.

Comment: please explain the pattern. Why does this work?

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
preg_match_all('#<span class="[^"]*last_position[^"]*">(.+)</span>#', $string, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

You'll then find the values in `$matches[1][0]`, `$matches[1][1]`, `$matches[1][2]` ....

The part I added in the class attributes value `[^"]*` matches any number of characters that does not match a doublequote. Thus it matches anything inside the attributes value.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, parsing **XML** is not possible using RegEx, because XML is not regular. But in many real-world cases, XML documents used as input are limited and predictable enough to simply be treated as text.

Something like this should work for you:

```
preg_match('#<span class="[^>"]*?last_position[^>"]*">(.+)</span>#', $string, $matches);
```

Comment: please explain the pattern. Why does this work?