# DOM XPath Selector not grabbing classes

Tags: php, dom, xpath, domdocument

I was looking through the following stackoverflow question: [Getting Dom Elements By Class name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6366351/getting-dom-elements-by-class-name) and it referenced that I can get class names with this code:

```
$text = '<html><body><div class="someclass someclass2">sometext</div></body></html>';
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($text);
$classname = 'someclass someclass2';
$finder = new DomXPath($dom);
$nodes = $finder->query("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' $classname ')]");
print "<pre>".print_r($nodes,true)."</pre>";
```

I also tried changing `$classname` to just one class:

```
$classname = 'someclass2';
```

I'm getting empty results. Any idea why?

Comment: This works for me see http://codepad.org/1O17uu5x http://codepad.org/Dk2f7o4Q

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to loop trough the results as `print_r()` will not print the members of a `DOMNodeList`. Like this:

```
$text = '<html><body><div class="someclass someclass2">sometext</div></body></html>';
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($text);
$classname = 'someclass someclass2';
$finder = new DomXPath($dom);
$nodes = $finder->query("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' $classname ')]");

// iterate through the result. print_r will not suffer
foreach($nodes as $node) {
    echo $node->nodeValue;
}
```

Comment: you are welcome. if you need it more often consider to write a function like `dump_xp_results()`