# PHP get text from HTML class

Tags: php, html

I'm working on a project where I need to get all the data from a HTML class.

```
<div class="sprofile">
    <a href="http://www.cibap.nl/profile/2127/"><b>Jeroen Rinzema</b></a>
    <br />
    <i>Reclame en Media</i>
    <br />
    Klas RMM21C
    <div class="istatus offline">
    Offline
    </div>                
</div>
```

This is the HTML that I need to get from the HTML page. But I don't know how I can select this part of the HTML document in PHP. The parts I need to use are:
**Jeroen Rinzema**
and
**Klas RMM21C**

If you want to see the full HTML document can you do that [here](http://pastebin.com/aHFeAPCj).

What I have tried so far is:

```
$url = "http://www.cibap.nl/profile/$username";
$html = file_get_html($url);
foreach($html->find('div.sprofile') as $article){
    $item['name'] = $article->find('div.sprofile a b', 0)->plaintext;
    $item['klas'] = $article->find('div.sprofile', 0)->plaintext;
}
echo'done';
```

Comment: but can i also select a class like (sprofile) with DOM Parser?

Comment: you can send this part via jquery to a php file i think both files must be in a same domain)

Comment: Both files are not in the same domain this is the HTML of a page on another server

Comment: @MeQube: Yes, that's easy. Use an XPath expression. Something like: `//*[contains(@class, 'sprofile')]` -- see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6366390/1438393) answer.

Comment: ok that is usefull so what i can do is selecting the class 'sprofile' and than grabbing the content 'Jeroen Rinzema' from <a href="http://www.cibap.nl/profile/2127/"><b></a></b>

Answer (score 1):

Use the Symfony [DomCrawler Component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html) with the [CssSelector Component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/css_selector.html). It provides a very natural syntax and allows you to select elements based on their class.

If PHP ain't a requirement, may I suggest using [nodejs](http://nodejs.org/) (with or without jQuery)?

Comment: the best would be php but if jQuery the only option is. Is it no problem

Comment: The thing with Symfony is that you select the text itself but in my situation is the text always different so i never know what is standing in the html file

Comment: @MeQube You use CSS classes in your example that can be matched with the CssSelector Component. If the DOM you're going to parse is always different, there's no way you can get the desired output automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Do you wish to send the html content to a php page?  For that you can wrap the content inside hidden form elements and POST the same.

If you wish to pick up the html content on this page itself,  use javascript dom manipulation.  You can go through this link toohttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808808/how-to-get-element-by-class-in-javascript

Answer (score -1):

Try PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

though if you're doing this client side use jQuery.