# Search html string using regular expression and store in array in PHP

Tags: php, html, regex, pcre

I need to search string which can be something like this:

```
<div class="icon_star">&nbsp;</div>
```

or

```
<div class="icon_star"></div>
```

or

```
<div class="icon_star"> </div>
```

I need to search above strings in HTML which could be something like this:

```
<h1 class="redword" tag="h1">
   <span class="BASE">good</span>
</h1>
<span class="headword-definition">&#160;-&#160;definition</span>
</span>
<div class="icon_star"></div>
<!-- End of DIV icon_star-->

<div class="icon_star"></div>
<!-- End of DIV icon_star-->

<div class="icon_star"></div>
<!-- End of DIV icon_star-->

</div><!-- End of DIV -->

<div class="headbar">
   <div id="helplinks-box" class="responsive_hide_on_smartphone">
```

String which we are trying to search and store in array can be multiple times

I have tried using the following regex:

```
preg_match_all ('/<div(\s)+class="icon_star">(.*?)<\/div>/i', $html1, $result_array1);
```

This above regex does not work when HTML to be searched is

```
<div id="headword">
    <div id="headwordright">
        <div style="display: none;" id="showmore"><a class="button" onmousedown="foldingSet(false)"><span class="label">Show more</span></a>
        </div><!-- End of DIV -->
        <div id="showless"><a class="button" onmousedown="foldingSet(true)"><span class="label">Show less</span></a>
        </div><!-- End of DIV -->
    </div><!-- End of DIV -->
    <span class="BASE-FORM">
        <h1 tag="h1" class="redword"><span class="BASE">scenario</span></h1>
        <span class="headword-definition">&nbsp;-&nbsp;definition</span>
    </span>
    <div class="icon_star">&nbsp;</div><!-- End of DIV icon_star-->
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried to use a regex already? If so, what is it (perhaps folks can help adjust it if you post it) if not - why haven't you tried anything on your own?

Comment: Tip: Don't. Use a native PHP class. Use something like DOMDocument or simplexml.

Comment: @Fluffeh:  yes, its something like this:: `preg_match_all ('/<div(\s)+class="icon_star">(.*?)<\/div>/i', $html1, $result_array1);`

Comment: @Farkie I need to do it using regular expression

Comment: Why? What's requiring it to be regex?

Comment: @D555 I have added your regex to the question. Hope you don't mind the edit. Saves folks trawling the comments (or more likely not trawling the comments).

Comment: @Fluffeh sure, thats fine

Comment: I don't see any question. That regex looks fine.

Comment: @bluskies the above regex does not work sometimes

Comment: @D555 such as? It works for your example in the question.

Comment: @bluskies such as this:: `<div id="headwordright"><div style="display: none;" id="showmore"><a class="button" onmousedown="foldingSet(false)"><span class="label">Show more</span></a></div><!-- End of DIV --><div id="showless"><a class="button" onmousedown="foldingSet(true)"><span class="label">Show less</span></a></div><!-- End of DIV --></div><!-- End of DIV --><span class="BASE-FORM"><h1 tag="h1" class="redword"><span class="BASE">scenario</span></h1><span class="headword-definition">&nbsp;-&nbsp;definition</span></span> <div class="icon_star">&nbsp;</div><!-- End of DIV icon_star--></div>`

Comment: @bluskies as above html contains icon-star div only once it should return array count as 1 but it returns 3 instead of 1.

Comment: Aha, now I see that there was some HTML that wasn't displaying correctly in the question. Fixed it.

Comment: @D555 are you relying on array count? then you shouldn't. You should look in the first index of the result array

Comment: @Ejay Thanks Ejay, yes I was looking at array count and thats why I was confused, thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**

It seems that you are reading your regexp results wrong way. Executing

```
preg_match_all('/<div(\s)+class="icon_star">.*?<\/div>/i', $html, $result_array1);

for($x = 0; $x < count($result_array1); $x++)
    $result_array1[$x] = array_map('htmlentities', $result_array1[$x]);

echo '<pre>' . print_r($result_array1, 1);
```

prints out

```
   Array
   (
       [0] => Array
       (
           [0] => <div class="icon_star">&nbsp;</div>
       )

       [1] => Array
       (
           [0] =>  
       )

   )
```

so you should be checking count of `$result_array1[0]` instead of `$result_array1`

**side note**

instead of parsing HTML with regex, you could use `DOMDocument` class built into PHP, if you can.
Using following code extracts three div's.

Be aware that you need to have valid HTML for this method to work.

```
  //your HTML with tag added to make it valid
  $html = '<div>
     <h1 class="redword" tag="h1">
        <span class="BASE">good</span>
     </h1>
     <span class="headword-definition"><span>&#160;-&#160;definition</span></span>
     <div class="icon_star"></div>
     <div class="icon_star"></div>
     <div class="icon_star"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="headbar">
     <div id="helplinks-box" class="responsive_hide_on_smartphone">
     </div>
  </div>';

  $dom = new DOMDocument();
  @$dom->loadHTML($html);
  $x = new DOMXPath($dom);

  //this xpath query looks for all nodes that have "class" attribute value equal to "icon_star"
  $nodes = $x->query("//*[contains(@class, 'icon_star')]");

  $res = '';
  foreach($nodes as $node) {
     /**
      * @var $node DOMElement
      */
     $res .= $dom->saveHTML($node);
  }

  echo htmlentities($res);
```

You could read following useful questions on stackoverflow
[How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php/3577662#3577662)
[Getting DOM elements by classname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6366351/getting-dom-elements-by-class-name)

Comment: Thanks Ejay but due to some reason I have been asked to do it strictly using regex but surely your answer will be useful to some other guy searching for help