# How to get the src of images php

Tags: php, html, json

So i have a load of images in html with the id `images`. An example of one is like this:

```
<img id="images" src="video images/the wind rises.jpg" alt="" width="700" height="525" class="the-wind-rises1" />
```

And I am wanting to collect all the srcs(eg. `video images/the wind rises.jpg`)
I have tried this. But it is not working how come?:

```
<?php
$html = file_get_contents('http://urlofwebsite.co.uk/xxxx');

function linkExtractor($html){
    $imageArr = array();
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    @$doc->loadHTML($html);
    $images = $doc->getElementById('images');
    foreach($images as $image) {
        array_push($imageArr, $image->getAttribute('src'));
    }
    return $imageArr;
}

echo json_encode(array("images" => linkExtractor($html)));
?>
```

It is just returning:

```
{"images":[]}
```

Comment: First, you can only legally have one element with any given `id`, so this is always going to be nasty. Second, using `@` is rarely if ever a good idea.

Comment: or you can use getbytag `$doc->getElementsByTagName('img');`

Comment: @lonesomeday Sometimes you need it. For example if you are parsing data, and not want to send a warning to the frontend (user). But you should check alltime, if it was successfull, and if not implement custom error handling (`throw new XmlNotValidException()`)

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt Why are you running with errors messages enabled on your production server?

Comment: @lonesomeday Thats not, what i have said. But why do you want to continue, if the state of you application is not the state youre expecting? Sure in production use, i either see no warning, but should i see in development stage so many warnings, that i don't see the warnings i am interessted in? If you do some own Exception Handling, it feels good to use `@`

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt But error messages represent something that needs fixing in your code. In this instance, the correct approach uses libxml_use_internal_errors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `getElementById` and this function is supposed to return one element or null take a look at : http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementbyid.php

I would say try the below:

```
$image = $doc->getElementById('images');
return $image->getAttribute('src');
```

if your intention is to collect sources for all images then you will have to use `getElementsByTagName` : http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php

```
function linkExtractor($html){
    $imageArr = array();
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    @$doc->loadHTML($html);
    $images = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
    foreach($images as $image) {
        array_push($imageArr, $image->getAttribute('src'));
    }
    return $imageArr;
}
```

Comment: my intention is to collect sources for all images with id `images`

Comment: in html `id` attribute should be unique, you can use `class` in your html instead. please read the id section of http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2

Comment: I tried this where i changed the id to the class but I am getting an error `Call to undefined method DOMDocument::getElementByClass()`

Comment: I don't see any function called `getElementsByClass` in `DOMDocument` API page, I would say you have two options : either get elements by TagName loop through all of them and just pick the ones that have className = 'images' or the other options is to use selectors like in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6366351/getting-dom-elements-by-class-name

Comment: how would you get elements by TagName loop through all of them and just pick the ones that have className = 'images' ??

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/domelement.getattribute.php#79074 this example is helpful take a look how he is looping through elements and getting attributes, in your case you will use `getAttribute('class')` and would need to do some debugging using `var_dump` and `echo` to see what you are getting and what further processing you need to do to check the class.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54138/discussion-between-mehdi-karamosly-and-maximilian).

Answer (score 0):

because ID is (should be) unique, it returns only one element

```
$images = $doc->getElementById('images');
array_push($imageArr, $images->getAttribute('src'));
```

Docs: http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementbyid.php