# php regex detect everything even newline

Tags: php, regex

this is my input :

```
<div class="entry-content">
    <p> Hey ! </p>
    <h2> How Are You ?! </h2>
</div><!-- .entry-content -->
```

and this is my RegEx !

```
"<div class=\"entry-content\">(.*?)</div><!-- .entry-content -->"
```

this work when there is no line between `<div>` tag like this

```
<div class="entry-content"> Hey ! </div><!-- .entry-content -->
```

But i need actually everything even new line other html tags and etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Take a look about the s modifier here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html and try to use DOMDocument instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [XML Parsing framework](http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.xml.php) like [`DOM`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) to parse XML documents (including HTML), but if you really need to use regex (assuming PCRE) there's an [`s` PCRE modifier](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php):

> `s (PCRE_DOTALL)`
>
> If this modifier is set, a dot metacharacter in the
>   pattern matches all characters, including newlines. Without it,
>   newlines are excluded. This modifier is equivalent to Perl's /s
>   modifier. A negative class such as [^a] always matches a newline
>   character, independent of the setting of this modifier.

So you may write:

```
$matches = array();
preg_match_all("~<div class=\"entry-content\">(.*?)</div><!-- \\.entry-content -->~s",
    $text, $matches);
```

*BTW: [Here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6366390/1149736) for you how to use DOM to fetch elements based on their class name.*

Answer (score 1):

Use the right [**tool**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) for the job instead of trying to parse this using a regular expression.

```
$html = <<<DATA
<div class="entry-content">
    Hey !
    How Are You ?!
</div><!-- .entry-content -->
DATA;

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$node  = $xpath->query('//div[@class="entry-content"]');

echo $node->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

Output

```
    Hey !
    How Are You ?!
```

Comment: that's Great thanks , i will try it later, but now i need to get html tags too , nodeValue is Just Text.