# How to delete element and its children using php's HTMLDOMDocument class

Tags: php, dom, domdocument

I'm relatively new to php's HTMLDOMDocument class.

I'm doing something like this:

```
$html = getHTML();

$htmlDOM = new DOMDocument('5.0', 'utf-8');
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$htmlDOM->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding(($html), 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));
libxml_clear_errors();
```

Unfortunately all the elements that are retrieved has classes, not IDs. Retrieving elements by Id or Tags are pretty straightforward...

But, how do I retrieve a few elements inside with a specific class (eg: `post-hover`) and then delete them from `$htmlDOM` ?

Answer (score 1):

No idea why they haven't added a getElementsByClassName yet. But you can use xpath to find the elements instead (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6366390/1301076)):

```
$finder = new DomXPath($dom);
$classname = "my-class";
$nodes = $finder->query("//*[contains(@class, '$classname')]");
```

Then simply loop through and delete:

```
foreach($nodes as $node){
    $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
}
```