# How can I transfer this js code to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, json

Can anyone help me convert this javascript script I wrote below to PHP? Any help would be appreciated:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.getJSON('inc/data.php',{format: "json"}, function(data) {
        var valC="";
        $.each(data['canales'], function(key, val) {
            var str = key;
            str = str.replace("_","-");
            valC=valC+'<li><a href="'+str+'.php" title="'+key+'"><img class="img-min-menu" src="http://cdn.vaughnsoft.com/vaughnsoft/vaughn/img_profiles/'+val+'_320.jpg" alt=""></a></li>';
        });

        $("#lista").html(valC);
    }); 
</script>
```

This php file generates a `json` string from an array:

http://pastebin.com/xmqvii2X

Comment: Are you able to edit page 2 or are you stuck with that?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Page 2, if it doesn't break other stuff elsewhere in your site, you are just going to remove the last lines of the script that converts the array to json then echos it

Comment: I'm trying to get all the thumbnails, this url "http://vaughnlive.tv/browse/espanol?a=mvn" to create a directory within my web page, where I only took the embed codes.

Comment: I thought you mean to put it in the post StackOverflow, not the pastebin

Comment: but as I have no knowledge about "scrap", choose it manually creating and editing the list page 2

Comment: Yeah I have only a little bit of scraping knowledge. When I am in front of a computer I will take a closer look.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are trying to do. See my notes, you have to uncomment one of the two options based on your capabilities and requirements:

```
class getJSON
    {
        protected   $valC;
        protected   $getFile;

        public  function __construct($filename = 'inc/data.php')
            {
                $this->valC     =   "";

                // If you can edit page two, remove lines 65 down on that page and uncomment this:
                // $this->doOpt1($filename);
                // If you are stuck with page two uncomment this:
                // $this->doOpt2($filename);
            }

        private function doOpt1($filename)
            {
                // Include the page
                include_once($filename);
                // Just assign the array
                $this->getFile  =   $lista->canales;
            }

        private function doOpt2($filename)
            {
                // Create a buffer
                ob_start();
                // Include the page which echos the json string
                include($filename);
                // Capture the buffer
                $data   =   ob_get_contents();
                // Flush
                ob_end_clean();
                // Decode the json
                $this->getFile  =   json_decode(trim($data),true);
            }

        public  function createLinks()
            {
                if(empty($this->getFile) || !is_array($this->getFile))
                    return $this->valC;

                foreach($this->getFile as $key => $val) {
                        $this->valC .=  '
                    <li>
                        <a href="'.str_replace("_","-",$key).'.php" title="'.$key.'">
                            <img class="img-min-menu" src="http://cdn.vaughnsoft.com/vaughnsoft/vaughn/img_profiles/'.$val.'_320.jpg" alt="">
                        </a>
                    </li>';
                    }

                return $this->valC;
            }
    }           

$makeLinks  =   new getJSON();
?>
<div id="lista"><?php echo $makeLinks->createLinks(); ?></div>
```

---

**EDIT**

After further discussion, it sounds like you want to scrape from the original. See if this is more what you are trying to do. It requires a cURL library and the DOM Library:

```
<?php

    class   cURL
        {
            public      $response;
            protected   $sendHeader;

            protected   $PostFields;

            private     $query;

            public  function    __construct($query = '')
                {
                    $this->sendHeader   =   false;
                    $this->query        =   $query;
                    if(!empty($this->query)) {
                            if(!is_array($this->query))
                                $this->response =   $this->Connect($this->query);
                            else
                                $this->encode();
                        }
                }

            public  function SendPost($array = array())
                {
                    $this->PostFields['payload']    =   $array;
                    $this->PostFields['query']      =   http_build_query($array);
                    return $this;
                }

            public  function Connect($_url,$deJSON = true)
                {
                    // Remote Connect
                    $ch         = curl_init();

                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $_url);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

                    if(strpos($_url,"https://") !== false) {
                            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,2);
                            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,2);
                        }

                    if(!empty($this->PostFields['payload'])) {
                            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($this->PostFields['payload']));
                            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $this->PostFields['query']);
                        }

                    if(!empty($this->sendHeader))
                        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11) AppleWebKit/601.1.56 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Safari/601.1.56');

                    $decode     =   curl_exec($ch);
                    $_response  =   ($deJSON)? json_decode($decode, true) : $decode;
                    $error      =   curl_error($ch);

                    curl_close($ch);
                    return (empty($error))? $_response: $error;
                }

            public  function emulateBrowser()
                {
                    $this->sendHeader   =   true;
                    return $this;
                }

            public  function encode($_filter = 0)
                {
                    foreach($this->query as $key => $value) {
                            $string[]   =   urlencode($key).'='.urlencode($value);
                        }

                    if($_filter == true)
                        $string =   array_filter($string);

                    return implode("&",$string);
                }
        }
```

**To use:**

```
// Create cURL instance
$curl   =   new cURL();
// Masquerade as a browser and get contents
$val    =   $curl   ->emulateBrowser()
                    ->Connect('http://vaughnlive.tv/browse/espanol?a=mvn%22',false);
// Create a DOM instance
$DOM    =   new DOMDocument();
// Process the returned data
@$DOM->loadHTML($val);
// Fetch the <a> elements
$aArray =   $DOM->getElementsByTagName('a');
// Loop through them and echo the html
foreach ($aArray as $node) {
    echo $DOM->saveHtml($node), PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: See if the above edit works. It will scrape the data from their page.

Comment: thank you so much for the help it works, i only have a question it's posible get for example this: [link](http://prntscr.com/8v1h72) i mean all div content not only <a></a> content.. this is because I want to give css styles and it would be better to get the entire contents of the div. i add a div to foreach:  <code>echo '<div id="xd">'. $DOM->saveHtml($node), PHP_EOL . "</div>";</code> but doesn't work: [link](http://prntscr.com/8v1hg4)

Comment: You might be able to get the div by class or something?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6366351/getting-dom-elements-by-classname