# How to get HTML site contents and manipulate its tags in PHP?

Tags: php, string, foreach, domdocument, file-get-contents

I'm trying to write a script that will get the html code of a site and will have to calculate the number of the `<li>` items within a particular `<ul>`.

```
<html>

<head>...</head>

<body>
    ...
    <ul class="the-list">
        ...
        <li>...</li>
        ...
    </ul>
    ...
</body>

</html>
```

So what I'm currently doing is to get the contents via `file_get_contents()`, but then I have to get this particular `<ul>` and somehow parse and foreach its `<li>`s. What's the best approach of doing that?

Thanks

Comment: you could use [DOMDocument.loadHtml(source)](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php), then retrieve the ul tag with class `the-list` using [the answer of this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6366351/getting-dom-elements-by-classname)

Comment: thanks, trying to do that currently

Comment: good luck, if it works, write an answer

Answer (score 0):

This can be done
but `<ul>` tag must have an Id for the below php snippet to work:

Load HTML then reference the target ul then the target sub tag that is `<li>` here

Like:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($HTML);
$allElements = $dom->getElementById('targetUlId')->getElementsByTagName('li');
echo $allElements->length;
```

This will echo the count of li tags inside the target ul

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I still have to foreach them as well. Also the `<ul>` doesn't have an ID unfortunately.

Comment: will there be only a single <ul> element with the class you mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');

foreach($html->find('li') as $element) 
       echo $element->plaintext. '<br>';
```

You can also use simplephpdom library

> http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/