# How can I get the span tag value using php curl and simple html dom parser?the exact value does not show

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

**code for this:**

```
  <span class="file-count-label" ng-init="totalResultCount=304575" ng-show="totalResultCount" style="">304,575</span>

$videos=$html->find('span[class=file-count-label]');
foreach($videos as $e)
{
  echo $e->plaintext;
}
```

output:{{totalResultCount | number}} but i want 304,575

Comment: it shows nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `xpath selector`

```
<?php

$html = '<span class="file-count-label" ng-init="totalResultCount=304575" ng-show="totalResultCount" style="">304,575</span>';
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$finder = new DomXPath($doc);
$classname="file-count-label";
$videos = $finder->query("//*[contains(@class, '$classname')]");

foreach($videos as $e)
{
  echo $e->nodeValue;
}
```

Output:- https://eval.in/1056186

Reference taken:- https://stackoverflow.com/a/6366390/4248328

Comment: but when i applying the same logic my output does not change.
https://eval.in/1056204 this is my code.
thanks

Comment: @JalisMahamud  the platform you used is not supporting `CURL`. try to run code at your end and check

Comment: @JalisMahamud  please ask a new question with your curl code, error description and what expected outcome you want. You will get help for-sure

Answer (score 0):

It works for me:

```
include 'simple_html_dom.php';
$html = str_get_html('<span class="file-count-label" ng-init="totalResultCount=304575" ng-show="totalResultCount" style="">304,575</span>');

$videos=$html->find('span[class=file-count-label]');
foreach($videos as $e)
{
  echo $e->plaintext; 
  // 304,575
}
```

Comment: I can't help you with that but I tried it and it worked for me.