# Php Replace in string Preg_match

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, preg-match

I want to check in wp if post content  includes gx-block class.
For example I can have

```
class="something_can_exists_or_not gx-block something_else" should print *true*

class="gx-block" *true*
Etc.
```

I have  tried  this but doesn't work

`preg_match('/class="?.*gx-block?.*"/i', $content);`

Thanks

Comment: Here you have answer for your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366730/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-contains-a-specific-word

Comment: you can use `strpos($content, 'gx-block')` for that as well.

Comment: Since you're parsing HTML, you'd be better off [using a DOM parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php).

Comment: Patryk  Parcheta thanks. I found there a solution

Comment: [Parsing HTML with regex is a hard job](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491/372239)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that regular expression is right tool for the job. As the HTML is not regular language.

Anyway you could do some think like this:

https://3v4l.org/ORKkR

```
const REGEX = '/class=("gx-block"|"gx-block .*"|".* gx-block")/i';


const HTML1 = '<div class="gx-block">abc</div>';
const HTML2 = '<div class="xyz">abc (gx-block) def</div>';
const HTML3 = '<div class="gx-blockhhh">abc</div>';


echo preg_match(REGEX, HTML1) ? 'true' : 'false';
echo PHP_EOL;
echo preg_match(REGEX, HTML2) ? 'true' : 'false';
echo PHP_EOL;
echo preg_match(REGEX, HTML3) ? 'true' : 'false';
echo PHP_EOL;
```

I would recommend doing it by DOM access instead as described here:
[Getting DOM elements by classname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6366351/getting-dom-elements-by-classname)

Comment: A bit better than previous answer but gives true for `<div class="xyz">abc "gx-block" def</div>`.

Comment: @Toto Yes. I don't think you can write such regex that will solve question. HTML is not regular language. Parsing DOM is way to go.

Comment: It's almost impossible, just have a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491/372239)