# Remove style attribute from certain HTML tags in a document and replace with class attribute

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

For instance I have a string:

```
$string = '<div class="ImageRight" style="width:150px">';
```

which I want to transform into this:

```
$string = '<div class="ImageRight">';
```

1. I want to remove the portion
   `style="width:150px` with `preg_replace()` where the
   size 150 can vary, so the width can be
   500px etc. aswell.
2. Also, the last part of the classname varies aswell, so the class can be ImageRight, ImageLeft, ImageTop etc.

So, how can I remove the style attribute completely from a string with the above mentioned structure, where the only things that varies is the last portion of the classname and the width value?

EDIT: The ACTUAL string I have is an entire html document and I don't want to remove the style attribute from the entire html, only from the tags which match the string I've shown above.

Comment: A great source to learn regular expressions: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: will the class/style tags always appear the same way round?

Comment: is this part of a html document or will there only ever be that div?

Comment: possible duplicate of [php regexp: remove all attributes from an html tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3026096/php-regexp-remove-all-attributes-from-an-html-tag)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're after...

```
$modifiedHtml = preg_replace('/<(div class="Image[^"]+") style="[^"]+">/i', '<$1>', $html);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove completely.

```
$string = preg_replace("/style=\"width:150px\"/", "", $string);
```

Replace:

```
$string = preg_replace("/style=\"width:150px\"/", "style=\"width:500px\"", $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two steps with

```
$place = 'Left';
$size = 500;
$string = preg_replace('/(?<=class="image)\W(?=")/',$place,$string);
$string = preg_replace('/(?<=style="width:)[0-9]+(?=")/',$size,$string);
```

Note: `(?=...)` is called a lookahead.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$string = preg_replace('/(div class="Image.+?") style="width:.+?"/', "$1", $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
$string  = preg_replace('/<div class="Image(.*?)".*?>/i', '<div class="Image$1">', $string);
```