# Regex to remove id attributes from HTML

Tags: php, html, regex

I have an html with a lot of `id="something"` attributes.

All the html is inside `$data` var.

Trying to remove all the `id="*"` from `$data`:

```
$data = preg_replace('\<id="[*]"^\>', '', $data);
```

Doesn't work, whats wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [php regexp: remove all attributes from an html tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3026096/php-regexp-remove-all-attributes-from-an-html-tag)

Comment: What's with the editing history here? -- Your first problem might be the choice or lack of regex delimiters (see the manual).

Comment: editing is quite messy, because of a good beer. sry

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
$data = preg_replace('#\s(id|class)="[^"]+"#', '', $data);
```

*Note: We solved the remaining issues in chat. The answer still fits the problem described in the question.*

Comment: `[...]` defines a group of characters. If you prefix them with `^` you mean the complement. So `[^"]` means any character except for `"`.

Comment: very nice. Any idea how to make this code work only for <li[*]</li>?

Comment: At that point I probably should tell you that using regex to parse HTML is a very bad idea. Consider `<li style="something" id="foo" class="bar">` for example. There are so many different possibilities for where `id` and `class` could be located within `<li>` that writing a regex for that is unnecessarily tedious. You would have to consider all possible combinations of `class`, `id` and any other attribute that is allowed within `<li>`.

Comment: there are only class and id inside li

Comment: Well...if that is the case, you could replace every `<li ...>` with `<li>`: `preg_replace('#<li[^>]+>#', '<li>', $data);`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4504/discussion-between-till-helge-helwig-and-messi)

Comment: Perfect Solution for remove all class & ids only from html tags ... Thanks

Answer (score 5):

try the following:

```
'id="[^"]*"'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = preg_replace('#<id=".*?"/>#', '', $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = preg_replace('/(<([^>]*))(id=("[^"]*"|[^" >]*))/', '$1', $data);
```

it eliminate also id=foo (without ") in tag and keep id= out of tag