# How do I erase all styles from HTML using PHP?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php regexp: remove all attributes from an html tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3026096/php-regexp-remove-all-attributes-from-an-html-tag)

```
$input = '<div style="font-size: 18px; line-height: 20px;" id="whatever">text</div>';

// ... some code here, probably regex

$desired_output = '<div id="whatever">text</div>';
```

How do I do the above using PHP?

Comment: I don't want to remove all attributes, I only want to remove the "style" attribute!

Comment: There are some good examples in the duplicate question which show how to specifically remove the style tag or only remove a single attribute.

Comment: @RIMMER my answer in that question shows exactly that. And there is also plenty additional duplicates explaining how to remove an attribute from an element. Also have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820666/grabbing-the-href-attribute-of-an-a-element/3820783#3820783

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following you need a regular expression to strip it out.

```
$desired_output = preg_replace('/<\s*style.+?<\s*\/\s*style.*?>/si', ' ', $input );
```

or this

```
$desired_output = preg_replace('%style="[^"]+"%i', '', $input);
```

Comment: And once again I find myself having to post this link.  You can't parse HTML with regex. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/477127

Comment: @GordonM: A DOM solution might be better, but using regex to extract information from HTML is a completely valid solution as long as it works.

Comment: @Blender - Except that it won't work, hence why it is an invalid solution.