# Clean code from Javascript with specific method

Tags: javascript, php

I have this string ($str) and I'm trying to prevent Javascript execution:

```
<script> ... </script>
<link onload="...">
<div onmouseover="...">
```

I apply these commands:

```
$find = Array("script", "onload", "onmouseover");
$rep = Array("noscript", "no_onload", "no_onmouseover");

$new = str_replace($find, $rep, $str);
```

Working example: http://codepad.org/kwuQvRiM

I know there are other event attributes but to make the question shorter I've choosen just 3 elements/attributes, but.

If I allow users to populate `$str` instead of declare it in the PHP source ( `$str = $_GET["str"]` for example), so an user can changes the `$str` code can somehow exploit this protection?

Imagine that `$new` is stored in a database and used later, I want to know if the string will be safe from javascript execution.

**N.B. I know there are safer ways to perform this task but this question is for a didactic study and I need to perform in this way**

Comment: Why not just use `strip_tags`? That is even safer.

Comment: some input, $str = $_GET["str"] etc

Comment: I know put, but I need an answer to this question in this way.

Comment: Here is something similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3026096/remove-all-attributes-from-an-html-tag

Comment: What are you replacing these with?

Comment: @putvande Possibly to keep `<i>` and so on available

Comment: How could the user change `$str` value? Unless it comes via HTTP Request, there's no way of doing so.

Comment: I've explained the `$str` part better

Comment: So what if they changed `$str`? What would that even matter?

Comment: imagine the `$new` is sent to a database etc etc etc

Comment: @FezVrasta You are stripping the script elements AFTER you get the `$str`. They can't modify it further at that point...

Comment: @FezVrasta You are sanitizing the `$str` before you put it in the database, and after you get it from the HTTP request. There is no way they can reinject the javascript code at that point. So yes, it is safe *to the point of the protection your sanitization code provides.* **Are you actually asking us if there are any other ways they can insert scripts into HTML besides what you've listed in your question?**

Comment: there aren't exploits to write an input that will not be sanitized? (special chars not read by browsers etc)?

Comment: @FezVrasta If the browser doesn't read it, why/how would it execute it?

Comment: @crush No, I know there are bunch of tags which can run javascript, I want to know if is enough replace all the tags.

Comment: The only reason that escaped or special chars would be a problem is if your sanitize code didn't handle them correctly and/or converted them automatically into non-escaped/special chars.

Comment: there aren't hacks like the ones for CSS in explorer? `<scr[somethingstrange]ipt>alert("");</scr[somethingstrange]ipt>` for example.