# use strip_tags() to remove tag attributes, in addition to tags

Tags: php

I am aware and know how to use strip_tags() with php, but I am wanting to remove all stylings that are contained in those tags.

I need to retain the following tags only

```
<p></p>
<a></a>
<br />
```

Not sure br is considered a tag with strip_tags, so I included it.

Example Before:

```
<p style="font-family: Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; padding: 0px; margin: 3px 0px 10px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); line-height: 16px;">
```

After:

```
<p>
```

Problem is I am not sure if I can accomplish this with strip tags or if I also need to include a preg_replace with some REGEX. Also the styling can vary at times so it needs to be something that can handle anything.

I found an example on php.net but does not seem to work

```
function strip_tags_content($text, $tags = '', $invert = FALSE) { 

  preg_match_all('/<(.+?)[\s]*\/?[\s]*>/si', trim($tags), $tags); 
  $tags = array_unique($tags[1]); 

  if(is_array($tags) AND count($tags) > 0) { 
    if($invert == FALSE) { 
      return preg_replace('@<(?!(?:'. implode('|', $tags) .')\b)(\w+)\b.*?>.*?</\1>@si', '', $text); 
    } 
    else { 
      return preg_replace('@<('. implode('|', $tags) .')\b.*?>.*?</\1>@si', '', $text); 
    } 
  } 
  elseif($invert == FALSE) { 
    return preg_replace('@<(\w+)\b.*?>.*?</\1>@si', '', $text); 
  } 
  return $text; 
}
?>
<?=strip_tags_content($row['notes'])?></p>
```

Comment: Why not try this ? `echo strip_tags($text, '<p><a><br>');`

Comment: Please post your relevant PHP code too.

Comment: `strip_tags()` sees a tag as **a case-insensitive string between `<` and the first whitespace or `>`.**

Comment: First, [remove all attributes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3026096/remove-all-attributes-from-an-html-tag) and then use `strip_tags()`.

Comment: right so my guess is that I need to preg_replace with some regex first the <p style="..." first and remove it completely, then run the strip_tags on it. I was hoping that I could do it all in one shot with just strip_tags

Comment: BOOM! @BurhanKhalid that was PERFECT. Post that as a solution so I can close this please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like:

```
$x = preg_replace("/<(p|a|b|div) [^>]*>/", "<$1>", $x);
```

With all your relevant tags in there of course.
Note that this will fail in cases where any parameter has a > sign in it so you must cope with quotes somehow.

Comment: Anyway to put them back? I need to remove attributes from html tags to pass the string to a translator and I'd like to put them back afterwards.

Comment: @MiguelGisbert I'm not sure you can do that; once you strip the inside, you can't identify tags. Maybe you can explode("<",$x) and remember the array index of each one, but there's no guarantee the translator won't change the structure so you can't be sure anymore.

Comment: what if I put a special char and substitute all the special chars with the stripped tags in the same order? the point is that I wasn't able to get properly all the html tags (open and close ones) on an array

Comment: @MiguelGisbert Something like that could be an option - again, I don't know what the translator does but if you get the same number of tags in the same order, the answer is yes.

Answer (score -2):

You can use JQuery instead if you simply want to remove the style from the elements after executing `strip_tags($text, '<p><a><br>')`

### JQuery code

```
$("container").children().each(function()
    {
        $(this).attr('style','');
    });
```

**[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/54rS2/1/)**