# how do I use preg_replace_callback on unknown values?

Tags: php, regex

I got some great help today with starting to understand preg_replace_callback with known values. But now I want to tackle unknown values.

```
$string = '<p id="keepthis"> text</p><div id="foo">text</div><div id="bar">more text</div><a id="red"href="page6.php">Page 6</a><a id="green"href="page7.php">Page 7</a>';
```

With that as my string, how would I go about using preg_replace_callback to remove all id's from divs and a tags but keeping the id in place for the p tag?

so from my string

```
<p id="keepthis"> text</p>
<div id="foo">text</div>
<div id="bar">more text</div>
<a id="red"href="page6.php">Page 6</a>
<a id="green"href="page7.php">Page 7</a>
```

to

```
<p id="keepthis"> text</p>
<div>text</div>
<div>more text</div>
<a href="page6.php">Page 6</a>
<a href="page7.php">Page 7</a>
```

Comment: _“how would I go about using preg_replace_callback to […]”_ - ideally, [you wouldn’t](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) …

Comment: so I should just stick with preg_replace or str_replace in this case?

Comment: If you don't know the future of $string it is best to use a HTML parser

Comment: [A quick fiddle](http://regex101.com/r/aV9vK6), quite tired to post an extensive answer so I've put some comments. Use `preg_replace()` with the `x` modifier and remove the `g` modifier. Some advice : **1)** If you're not sure about the input you're getting or your regex skills aren't good then just use [a parser](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3577641) **2)** This question got quite some upvotes, I don't see why but you really should post your attempts **3)** [Learn regex](http://regex.learncodethehardway.org/book) or visit the [regex chatroom](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25767) !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need of a callback.

```
$string = preg_replace('/(?<=<div|<a)( *id="[^"]+")/', ' ', $string);
```

[Live demo](http://regex101.com/r/gH8jK5)

However in the use of `preg_replace_callback`:

```
echo preg_replace_callback(
    '/(?<=<div|<a)( *id="[^"]+")/',
    function ($match)
    {
        return " ";
    },
    $string
 );
```

[Demo](http://3v4l.org/lcTiS)

Comment: Thank you for giving examples of both!

Answer (score 0):

For your example, the following should work:

```
$result = preg_replace('/(<(a|div)[^>]*\s+)id="[^"]*"\s*/', '\1', $string);
```

Though in general you'd better **avoid parsing HTML with regular expressions** and use a proper parser instead (for example load the HTML into a DOMDocument and use the [removeAttribute](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domelement.removeattribute.php) method, like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3026411/943102)). That way you can handle variations in markup and malformed HTML much better.