# Removing attributes from HTML Tags with PHP

Tags: php, preg-replace, strip-tags

How to remove table's attributes like `height, border-spacing and style="";`

```
<table style="border-collapse: collapse" border="0" bordercolor="#000000" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" height="80" width="95%">
```

to this -->

```
<table>
```

`strip_tags` works for ripping tags off, but what about `preg_replace`?

FYI: loading stuff from database and it has all these weird styling and I want to get rid of them.

Comment: [DOM](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) not regex.

Comment: It would be helpful if your examples didn't confuse CSS properties with HTML attributes and actually matched the code sample you were talking about.

Comment: Duplicate: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php

Comment: Many options, both regex and dom: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3026096/remove-all-attributes-from-an-html-tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to use preg_replace, this is the way to go, but keep in mind that preg_replace isn't reliable

```
$output = preg_replace('/(<[^>]+) style=".*?"/i', '$1', $html);
```

I recommend you to use php DOM that exists for this kind of operation :

```
// load HTML into a new DOMDocument
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);

// Find style attribute with Xpath
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$styleNodes = $xpath->query('//*[@style]');

// Iterate over nodes and remove style attributes
foreach ($styleNodes as $styleNode) {
  $styleNode->removeAttribute('style');
}

// Save the clean HTML into $output
$output = $dom->saveHTML();
```