# Validation like Strip_tags for HTML Attributes

Tags: php, html, attributes, strip-tags

Is there a function like Strip_Tags() for the HTML Attributes?

F.e.:
`Strip_Attributes('<img src="url.png"/>', array("img" => "src"));`

-> `<img src="url.png"/>`

But 
`Strip_Attributes('<img src="url.png" onclick="alert(\'evil\');"/>', array("img" => "src"));`

-> `<img src="url.png"/>`

Comment: Not specifically no. What's this for? XSS protection?

Comment: Looks Like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3026096/remove-all-attributes-from-an-html-tag

Comment: @JonStirling I have a ckeditor-input with HTML-tags. Some of the tags have some attributes too and you can manipulate the attributes with Firefox easily. The output of the editor will be shown on another site. So some editor can insert his own js code which is not wanted.

Comment: @Paules I can rewrite his code to get what I want but I hoped that there is already some function like the strip_tags.

Comment: @GURKE Nope, there isn't. If there was a function like that why would he write that code then?

Comment: @Paules As i said, "I hoped" ... I didn't find that thread before nor stackoverflow presented it.