# Dealing with user input HTML

Tags: php, html

I have a simple textarea where users can input a description for their product on my dummy system. I'm only allowing `<b>` `<u>` and `<i>` tags, without any attributes using the following code:

```
$description = strip_tags($_POST['description'], "<b><u><i>");
$description = preg_replace("/<([a-z][a-z0-9]*)[^>]*?(\/?)>/i",'<$1$2>', $description);
```

My problem is when a tag is left without it's closing part, for example:

```
<b>This is a <i>Test
```

The `<b>` and `<i>` tags will apply to everything that comes after this part. Is there any reliable way to automatically close the tags?

What I want is for the tag to be closed on the end of the user input, but only if it was left open.

Comment: How would you know where to automatically close the tag? What exactly is the desired behavior?

Comment: Show the incoming _string_.

Comment: @nullability Edited the question with the desired behavior. I want it to be closed right after the user input ends, but only if he left it unclosed.

Comment: Also, your regex looks slightly strange. What were you trying to do?

Comment: @EugeneR I got the regex from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3026096/remove-all-attributes-from-an-html-tag?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving the problem by using Tidy. Here's the code:

```
$tidy = new Tidy();
$description = $tidy->repairString($description, array(
    'output-xml' => true,
    'input-xml' => true,
    'vertical-space' => false
));
```

Answer (score 0):

This code would require some additional finetuning but it will help you to get the gist of the idea.

```
$tags = ['b', 'i', 'u'];

foreach($tags as $t){
  if($a = substr_count($message, "<$t>") != $b = substr_count($message, "</$t>"){
    if($a > $b){
      $message .= str_repeat("<$t>", $a - $b);
    } else {
      // more closing tags then opening.
      $message = strrev($message);
      str_replace("<$t/>", '', $message, $b - $a);
      $message = strrev($message);
    }
  }
}
```

`$message` holds the entire text area text. It counts all the tags and if there is an inconsistency it will append at the end of the string.