# Delete "width" in style property inside table with preg_replace PHP

Tags: php, html, regex, html-table, preg-replace

I've got HTML code like below:

```
<p style="text-align: center; width: 200px">Hellow world</p>
<table style="width: 500px; font-family: Arial; font-size: 18px">
  <td style="width: 20px; color: red">One</td>
  <td style="width: 50px; color: green">Two</td>
  <td style="width: 100px; color: blue">Three</td>
</table>
```

I need **preg_replace** pattern for PHP that will remove only width property from **all tags** (td, tr, thead, tbody) inside table.

```
<p style="text-align: center; width: 200px">Hellow world</p>
<table style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 18px">
  <td style="color: red">One</td>
  <td style="color: green">Two</td>
  <td style="color: blue">Three</td>
</table>
```

So far I come up with this:

```
// deleting style attribute from table    
$sHtml = preg_replace('%<table[^>]*?style\s*=\s*"[^"]*"[^>]*>(.*?)</table>%si', '<table>$1</table>', $sHtml);
// deleting style attribute from td
$sHtml = preg_replace('%<td[^>]*?style\s*=\s*"[^"]*"[^>]*>(.*?)</td>%si', '<td>$1</td>', $sHtml);
```

Which deletes all whole style property inside table and tds:

```
<p style="text-align: center; width: 200px">Hellow world</p>
<table>
   <td>One</td>
   <td>Two</td>
   <td>Three</td>
</table>
```

Comment: Possibly duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3026096/remove-all-attributes-from-an-html-tag.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove all attributes from an html tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3026096/remove-all-attributes-from-an-html-tag)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
// deleting style attribute from table    
$sHtml = preg_replace('/(<table|tr|td|tbody|thead)(.*)(width: [0-9]+px;)/i', '$1$2', $sHtml);
```

Comment: Thank you! It helped me.