# Remove the contents within html tags but keeping the tag itself

Tags: php

I would like to remove the contents of a tag, but not the tag itself. For example to change:

```
<p style=' ... ' class = ' ...' etc etc> text </p>
```

to:

```
<p> text </p>
```

Using:

```
strip_tags($text, '<p>')
```

leaves the contents of the para tag inside but I would like it removed if possible.

Comment: You can remove tag attributes with JS

Comment: just search what you are asking for! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3026096/remove-all-attributes-from-an-html-tag

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia Thanks - didn't find that when I looked before. Very helpful.

Comment: i've just searched to "remove tag attributes php" and it's the first result... however, you're welcome