# Remove HTML Attributes using PHP

Tags: php

Using **PHP** i want to remove all **HTML** attributes except

> **"src"** attribute from **"img"** tag

and

> **"href"** attribute from **"a"** tag

My Input file is **.html** file which is been converted from **.doc** and **.docx**

My output file again should be **HTML file** with removed attribute

Kindly help me please

***Edit ::***

After Trying alexander script as below if i open the strip.html in code editor i don't see any changes

```
<?php
$path = '/var/www/strip.html';
$html = file_get_contents($path);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->strictErrorChecking = false;
$dom->formatOutput = true;
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
if (false === ($elements = $xpath->query("//img"))) die('Error');

foreach ($elements as $element) {
    for ($i = $element->attributes->length; --$i >= 0;) {
        $name = $element->attributes->item($i)->name;
        if ('src' !== $name) {
            $element->removeAttribute($name);
        }
    }
}

if (false === ($elements = $xpath->query("//a"))) die('Error');

foreach ($elements as $element) {
    for ($i = $element->attributes->length; --$i >= 0;) {
        $name = $element->attributes->item($i)->name;
        if ('href' !== $name) {
            $element->removeAttribute($name);
        }
    }
}

$dom->saveHTMLFile($path);

?>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2994448/regex-strip-html-attributes-except-src

Comment: @stefan how to make it work as if i input html and click a button i should ask to save the processed html file ???

Comment: That link should help you get started, I'm not going to architect your app for you but after you get your html, however that be, pass it through the regex(es).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [DOMDocument](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) class for parsing HTML (**"a"** and **"img"** tags processing):

```
$path = '/path/to/file.html';
$html = file_get_contents($path);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
//$dom->strictErrorChecking = false;
$dom->formatOutput = true;
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
if (false === ($elements = $xpath->query("//img"))) die('Error');

foreach ($elements as $element) {
    for ($i = $element->attributes->length; --$i >= 0;) {
        $name = $element->attributes->item($i)->name;
        if ('src' !== $name) {
            $element->removeAttribute($name);
        }
    }
}

if (false === ($elements = $xpath->query("//a"))) die('Error');

foreach ($elements as $element) {
    for ($i = $element->attributes->length; --$i >= 0;) {
        $name = $element->attributes->item($i)->name;
        if ('href' !== $name) {
            $element->removeAttribute($name);
        }
    }
}

$dom->saveHTMLFile($path);
```

Also, read [why you can't parse [X]HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2648942) and take a look at [useful xpath links](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xpath/info).

**Update** (all tags with exception **"a"** and **"img"** attributes processing):

```
$path = '/path/to/file.html';
$html = file_get_contents($path);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
//$dom->strictErrorChecking = false;
$dom->formatOutput = true;
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
if (false === ($elements = $xpath->query("//*"))) die('Error');

foreach ($elements as $element) {
    for ($i = $element->attributes->length; --$i >= 0;) {
        $name = $element->attributes->item($i)->name;
        if (('img' === $element->nodeName && 'src' === $name)
            || ('a' === $element->nodeName && 'href' === $name)
        ) {
            continue;
        }

        $element->removeAttribute($name);
    }
}

$dom->saveHTMLFile($path);
```

Comment: THis is outputing the same file as input...

What i did : saved the code you gave as php , changed the $path value to the input file path also added a new string $pathh for output path and in last line changed $path to $pathh .. loaded the php file in browser .i received the output as same as input in the $pathh dir .. attributes was not removed

Comment: @PHPGeany Definitely, you did something wrong, because this code is ok. Proof: [codepad link](http://codepad.org/TIcGuAHw)

Comment: @PHPGeany "loaded the php file in browser"? Do you have installed http-server on your local machine? Did you try to run this code through console, like "php codesource.php"? Browsers haven't integrated php-interpreter, thats why loading php-code in browser does nothing.

Comment: find the edit i made in my original question 

i use lamp stack i tried using local browser as localhost/path.php

Comment: Do you have any errors/warnings in error_log? Try to change `$dom->saveHTMLFile($path);` to `var_dump($dom->saveHTML());` to see if there is problems with attribs removing.

Comment: @PHPGeany I don't see any **"a"** or **"img"** tags in [tool.setinfotec.com/sof.php source](http://tool.setinfotec.com/sof.php). Thats why you can't see any changes :) If you want remove other tags attribs like **"p"** or **"div"**, you need to modify code. My code is just example for **"a"** and **"img"** tags...

Comment: in line 977 in page source there is image tag and many other lines

Comment: after using var dumb it displays string(106966) " at the top and " at the bottom

Comment: @PHPGeany My falult, sorry. There is really some "img" tags. But they're only with **"src"** attribs. Seems script is ok.

Comment: actually what i asked was i want to remove all attributes in all tags except src attribute in img tag and href attribite in a tag .. can u kindly provide me the code for that please

Comment: thanks a ton it does ... thanks a lot .. 

if you dont mind . i want it as upload the html sorce file and the browser ask me to save the processed file..

sorry for troubling ... it will mean a lot to me now ..

Comment: @PHPGeany You're welcome :) Well, you can ask another question about how to implement form with source and destination files paths

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23127036/how-to-implement-form-with-source-and-destination-files-paths

Comment: That answer doesn't comply your requirements. I deleted it.

Comment: Ok .. I clearly made my req here in below link  .. kindly look at it and answer if possible mate pls .. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23129320/php-dom-implementation

Comment: Kindly look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23210247/dom-tag-and-attribute-rules-and-filtering