# DOM Tag and Attribute Rules and Filtering

Tags: php, html, dom

I am using the following code for converting doc and docx to stripped html

```
<?php
class docxhtml
{
    /** @var string */
    private $tag;
    /** @var string */
    private $attribute;

    public $connectname;
    public $connectpass;

    public function __construct($format_res, $flname)
    {
        require_once('config.php');
        // Turn up error reporting
        error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

        // Turn off WSDL caching
        ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled', 0);

        // Define credentials for LD
        define ('USERNAME', $this->connectname);
        define ('PASSWORD', $this->connectpass);

        // SOAP WSDL endpoint
        define ('ENDPOINT', 'https://api.livedocx.com/2.1/mailmerge.asmx?wsdl');

        // Define timezone
        date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');

        // Instantiate SOAP object and log into LiveDocx
        $this->soap = new SoapClient(ENDPOINT);

        $this->soap->LogIn(
            array('username' => USERNAME, 'password' => PASSWORD)
        );

        // Upload template
        $this->data = file_get_contents('Original/' . $format_res);

        $this->soap->SetLocalTemplate(
            array('template' => base64_encode($this->data), 'format' => 'docx')
        );

        $this->result = $this->soap->RetrieveDocument(
            array('format' => 'html')
        );

        $this->data = $this->result->RetrieveDocumentResult;

        $exceptions = array(
            'a'   => array('href'),
            'img' => array('src')
        );

        $this->stripAttributes($exceptions);

        file_put_contents('Recode/' . $flname . '.html', base64_decode($this->data));
    }

    public function stripAttributes(array $exceptions)
    {
        $dom = new DOMDocument();
        $dom->strictErrorChecking = false;
        $dom->formatOutput = true;
        $dom->loadHTML(base64_decode($this->data));

        $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
        if (false === ($elements = $xpath->query("//*"))) die('Xpath error!');

        /** @var $element DOMElement */
        foreach ($elements as $element) {
            for ($i = $element->attributes->length; --$i >= 0;) {
                $this->tag       = $element->nodeName;
                $this->attribute = $element->attributes->item($i)->nodeName;

                if ($this->checkAttrExceptions($exceptions)) continue;

                $element->removeAttribute($this->attribute);
            }
        }

        $this->data = base64_encode($dom->saveHTML());
    }

    public function checkAttrExceptions(array $exceptions)
    {
        foreach ($exceptions as $tag => $attributes) {
            if (empty($attributes) || !is_array($attributes)) {
                die('Attributes not set!');
            }

            foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
                if ($tag === $this->tag && $attribute === $this->attribute) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Now what i want was to add rules and filters to the resulting html output as follows

1) All centered heading  should be `Div` tag now currently it is `P` tag

```
Sample : http://oi58.tinypic.com/2b6v0k.jpg
```

2) Also Author name under centered heading should be in separate `Div` tag which is also now in `P` tag ("Like the word - Francis Bacon in above Sample Picture")

3) Rest all headings should be in `P` Tag with attribute `class ="h1 or h2 or..h"` where the `h` value should be detected with font size

4) If there is only single line within `<li>` tag then it should be `<li> content </li>` currently it is `<li><p>content </p></li>`

5) suppose if the `<li>` tag contains multiple lines there should be `p` tag

6) Remove all `Span` tags

Kindly provide me advice and guidance on doing it please ...

Edit : Link for Html File to be Converted `http://www64.zippyshare.com/v/80261796/file.html`

Comment: Your first two 'rules' doesn't make sense to me - there is not enough information. It would be helpful if you shared a sample HTML document that you want converting also.

Comment: @jonnu Added html file link as edited in my original post bottom section .. 

For ref : http://www64.zippyshare.com/v/80261796/file.html

Comment: I'm just checking over the HTML source. It's tag soup with no semantic information - it is almost impossible to perform steps 1, 2, 3 on this document - not in a way that would be reusable for another document, I suspect. Could you write out, in a sentence, exactly how you want the code to determine what tag contains a heading, and what tag contains the author's name, for example?

4, 5 & 6 are definitely achievable, however, using PHP's `DOM` extension.

Comment: @jonnu can u please tell me point 6 alone rest i postponed ...just say what code should be added in my above said code to remove all span tags using dom .. Thanks a lot for replies mate

Comment: Sure, no problem. Answer posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**6. Removing tags**

In order to remove tags, you can leverage [getElementsByTagName](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php) since you know the 'name' of the tag that you want to remove. It's important when manipulating the DOM that you understand that the `DOMNodeList` object that it returns is dynamic, and will change as you alter the document. That is why in the below example, we store certain things (i.e. the node list and the number of nodes) in variables that will not change.  If you do not do this, you'll end up with odd behaviour. `$nodeList->item(0)` will always return the next matched tag that is unchanged, as we are modifying the DOM as we go.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTMLFile('english.html');

$nodeList  = $dom->getElementsByTagName('span');
$nodeCount = $nodeList->length;

for ($i = 0; $i < $nodeCount; $i++) {
    $span = $nodeList->item(0);
    $span->parentNode->replaceChild(new DOMText($span->textContent), $span);
}

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

The above may be a little too aggressive however if your HTML output has `<span>` elements that have child HTML tags. In order to remove all `<span>` tags, but retain child elements, you can use this method:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTMLFile('english.html');

$nodeList  = $dom->getElementsByTagName('span');
$nodeCount = $nodeList->length;

for ($i = 0; $i < $nodeCount; $i++) {

    $span    = $nodeList->item(0);
    $cleaned = $dom->createDocumentFragment();

    $childList  = $span->childNodes;
    $childCount = $childList->length;

    for ($j = 0; $j < $childCount; $j++) {
        $child = $childList->item(0);
        $cleaned->appendChild($child);
    }

    $span->parentNode->replaceChild($cleaned, $span);
}

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Comment: Thanks and already some dom codes are in my codes in question post .. can u tell me where to insert these codes pls ..

Comment: Shouldn't `$span = $nodeList->item(0);` be rather `$span = $nodeList->item($i);`? The $i is important!