# How to remove filepath substring from src value of img tags occurring in html text?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, filenames, src

I have some `<img>` tag `src` values that need to have their path removed.

Unfortunately, my html DOM is invalid, so I cannot use a DOM parser and must resort to regex.

My current attempt is:

```
src=(\'|")\/root\/images\/([^\/]*)\/([^(\'|"]*)
```

to turn this:

```
lots of other html
<img src="/root/images/ANY MORE PATH HERE/file.jpg">
more html
```

in to this:

```
lots of other html
<img src="file.jpg">
more html
```

The above will work when I just use capture group 3 only AND I have one directory beyond `/root/images`, but I don't know how many subdirectories will be in a given filepath.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you always only need the file name, basename function. http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php

Comment: to do that i would have to pull out all the img tags, process them and put them back in

Comment: What about the HTML is invalid? There are similar questions, with the upshot being to use a parser or dom. So maybe if you can fix the HTML part of it, that might work better? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138313/how-to-extract-img-src-title-and-alt-from-html-using-php http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120779/regex-php-isolate-src-attribute-from-img-tag http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10130858/get-img-src-with-php http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23109844/remove-html-attributes-using-php

Answer (score 1):

This uses preg_replace():

```
<?php
$foo = '/\/.+\//';
$test =  '<img src="/root/images/ANY MORE PATH HERE/file.jpg">';
echo preg_replace($foo, '', $test);
?>
```

Comment: with a slight variation this led me to the right answer, thanks

Comment: This only works when the entire html string is a single image tag.  That is not what the OP is dealing with.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you can match zero or more non-quote characters followed by a slash -- as many times as possible and replace that substring with an empty string.  This will always leave you with a `src` value that purely consists of the filename at the end of the path.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f76b72d9cd9219c118fce40a4ce370de4fd21ed0))

```
$html = <<<HTML
lots of other html
<img src="/root/images/ANY MORE PATH HERE/file.jpg">
more html
HTML;

echo preg_replace('~ src=[\'"]\K(?:[^\'"]*/)*~','',$html);
```

Output:

```
lots of other html
<img src="file.jpg">
more html
```

Pattern: `~ src=['"]\K([^'"]*/)*~`

([Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/1ELcWv/1))

Pattern Breakdown:

```
~          #pattern delimiter (deliberately not slash -- to avoid escaping)
 src=      #match a space followed literally by "src="
['"]       #match either single quote or double quote
\K         #restart the fullstring match (effectively forget previously matched characters)
(?:        #start of non-capturing group
  [^'"]*   #match zero or more non-single and non-double quote characters
  /        #match a forward slash
)          #end of non-capturing group
*          #allow zero or more occurrences of the non-capturing group
~          #pattern delimiter
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this is a simple solution using explode:

```
 $src = "/root/images/ANY MORE PATH HERE/file.jpg";
 $part = explode("/", $src);
 $imageName = $part[sizeof($part)-1]; //get the last index of the array
```

Comment: `<img src="/root/images/ANY MORE PATH HERE/file.jpg">` is just a small part of the string

Comment: as long as the image name at the end, this code will work. Print it out and give it a try.

Comment: This only works when the entire string is a single `src` attribute value.  That is not what the OP is dealing with.